# Bootstrap3: Why is the element's position moving to right as the modal-overlay appear

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Please take a look at my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xbdynv52/1/), and try to click the modal button menu.
As you can see, button menu and content are moving to right whenever the vertical-scroll hidden.
So, I tried [this:](https://jsfiddle.net/xbdynv52/2/)

```
body.modal-open{
    padding-right: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

the code above can keep the vertical-scroll visible, so the button won't moving to right anymore.

But, another problem is the `div.content`, it's moving to left.
Then, I tried this:

```
body.content{
  padding-right: 0px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

and nothing seems to work. I might be missing something here, need help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that some script (bootstrap ?) adds a `padding-right` css property to the body.

Solution: add a css property to the `body` which avoids this

```
   body { padding-right:0 !important;}
```

There's also the `modal-open .modal` selector which adds an overflow-y: scroll which may cause some displacement problem. If the above solution is not enough try to add

```
 modal-open .modal {
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

as well. But it should not be needed.

Comment: oh, i see, it's the `padding-right`, and this `body { padding-right:0 !important;} ` works for me. thanks @Massimo